# Stata error: missing string variable entry when actually does exist

Tags: string, stata, missing-data

I am attempting to code a dummy specification:

`replace var1 = 1 if state==AL & var2==.... & varN==3` (for example)

But, Stata tells me that `AL` (Alabama) cannot be found. However, I enter:

`tab state`

and, I can clearly see `AL` entries in my data, as well as when I observe my data directly. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: A quick note: this response holds for any state (TX, OH,...) that I attempt to use with this code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not enclosing string values between quotes: `... if state == "AL" ...` 
Without them, Stata looks for the *variable* `AL` and not the string *value*.

If not that, then you probably need to give more information on your problem.